# How to get a density from a forecast with prediction interval

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, prediction-interval, density-estimation

Some reproducible code to have in your environment a time series and a possible forecast:

```
packages <- c('forecast',
              'robets',
              'quantmod')
lapply(X = packages,
       FUN = function(package){
         if (!require(package = package,
                      character.only = TRUE))
         {
           install.packages(pkgs = package,
                            repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
           library(package = package,
                   character.only = TRUE)
         } else {
           library(package = package,
                   character.only = TRUE)    
         }
       })
getSymbols('GLD')
adjustOHLC(GLD)
GLD %>%
  Cl() %>%
  log() %>%
  robets() %>%
  forecast(h = 250, level = seq(from = 51, to = 99, by = 1)) %>%
  autoplot()
```

I would like to draw a random sample from the distribution of forecasted values, in order to possibly fit a probability density function. The value returned by `forecast` has some slots which might be useful, like `$mean` and `$residuals`, but I don't know how to draw such a sample. Furthermore, aside from this specific example, I would like to understand the theoretical procedure to get a density from a forecast with expected value and prediction interval only.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume a normal distribution of errors, then you can construct the distribution of the forecasts from the mean and the prediction intervals.

See [this blog post by Rob Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/quantile-forecasts-in-r/) for details.

Alternatively, you can generate sample paths for the forecasts, and then calculate the quantiles - in this case you don't even need the prediction intervals (but you still need to make assumptions on the distribution).